# Astrotomic Translatable - pivot column - Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, pivot, pivot-table, translation, laravel-9

I'm having trouble translating a pivot column.

I've been trying all day to add this translation but it still doesn't work.

I'm using the package: https://github.com/Astrotomic/laravel-translatable

Plain tables work fine, but pivot doesn't.

My code (the naming was quick, as the code will work, I'm going to refactor it):

```
class Offer extends Model implements TranslatableContract
                               use HasFactory, Translatable;
                         public array $translatedAttributes = [
                                'name',
                                'description'
                            ];
                         public function attributes(): BelongsToMany
                            {
                                return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'attribute_offer')->using(AttributeOffer::class)->withTimestamps();
                            }
                    
            class Attribute extends Model implements TranslatableContract
                        {
                            use HasFactory, Translatable;
                        
                        
                            public array $translatedAttributes = [
                                'name',
                            ];
                      public function values(): BelongsToMany
                        {
                            return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, 'attribute_offer', 'attribute_id', 'offer_id')->using(AttributeOffer::class);
                        }
                    
            class AttributeOffer extends Pivot implements TranslatableContract
                    {
                        use Translatable;
                    
                    
                        public $incrementing = true;
                    
                        public array $translatedAttributes = [
                            'content',
                        ];
                    
                    
                        protected $fillable = [
                            'attribute_id',
                            'offer_id',
                        ];
                    }
    class AttributeOfferTranslation extends Model
        {
            protected $table = 'attribute_offer_translations';
        
            public $timestamps = false;
        
            protected $fillable = [
                'content',
            ];
        }
  class OfferController extends Controller
                {
                  private function updateAttributeValues($offer, $attributes)
                    {
                    foreach ($attributes as $slug => $values) {
                            $pivot = $offer->attributes()->whereSlug($slug)->first()->pivot;
                            foreach ($values as $locale => $value) {
                                $pivot->translate($locale)->content = $value;
                            }
                }
            }
```

The structure of the attributes is:

```
[
    'test' =>[
    'en' =>  'test',
    'es' =>  'test',
    'de' =>  'test',
     ],
    'test2' =>[
    'en'=> 'test',
    'es'=> 'test',
    'de'  => 'test',
     ],
]
```

Unfortunately pivot->translate() always returns null.

[image]

Also, when I manually add transactions to the database, it does not display it.

I will be very grateful for help with this translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it like this, only I have to pass id instead of slugs.

```
class Offer extends Model implements TranslatableContract
{
...
    public function attributeValues(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AttributeOffer::class);
    }
}
```

```
class AttributeOffer extends Pivot implements TranslatableContract
{
...
    protected $translationForeignKey = 'attribute_offer_id';
...
}
```

```
private function updateAttributeValues($offer, $attributes)
  {
        foreach ($attributes as $id => $values) {
            $offer->attributeValues()->whereAttributeId($id)->first()->update($values);
        }
  }
```